# as3 - Creating common objects for all methods

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text-formatting

I'm building an application using Flash CS6 and AS3, where there will be loads of texts. So I want to create only one **text format** object for all of them. I am using this code:

```
public class MyClass extends MovieClip {

    public var formatTitle = new TextFormat();
    formatTitle.size = 50; <-- ERROR HERE

    public function MyClass(){
        buildHome();
    }

    public function buildHome(){
        var title:TextField = new TextField();
        title.text = "HOME";
        title.defaultTextFormat = formatTitle;
        addChild(title);
    }

}
```

But I'm getting the error: *Access of undefined property formatTitle* where it says **formatTitle.size = 50**. But it's here above it! What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `formatTitle.size = 50;` at the beginning of the constructor. You can't have code like this outside of a method.

```
public function MyClass(){
    formatTitle.size = 50;
    buildHome();
}
```